# How to delete a column in graphlab?

Tags: graphlab

I'm not getting to delete a column using graphlab
I have tried using

```
data.drop('X1','Unnamed:0',axis =1)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.remove_column.html), use remove_column.

```
import graphlab

sf = graphlab.SFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'val': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
sf.remove_column('val')
sf
```